# Window loses focus when closing font dialog

Tags: c, winapi

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK SecondWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        {
            HFONT hFont;
            LOGFONT lf;
            CHOOSEFONT cf = {0};

            hFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);

            GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);
            cf.Flags = CF_INITTOLOGFONTSTRUCT | CF_SCREENFONTS;
            cf.hwndOwner = hwnd;
            cf.lpLogFont = &lf;
            cf.lStructSize = sizeof(CHOOSEFONT);

            if(ChooseFont(&cf))
            {
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK FirstWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcFirst = {0}, wcSecond = {0};
    HWND hwndFirst, hwndSecond;
    MSG msg;

    wcFirst.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcFirst.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
    wcFirst.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wcFirst.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcFirst.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcFirst.lpfnWndProc = FirstWndProc;
    wcFirst.lpszClassName = TEXT("FirstClass");


    wcSecond.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcSecond.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
    wcSecond.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wcSecond.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcSecond.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcSecond.lpfnWndProc = SecondWndProc;
    wcSecond.lpszClassName = TEXT("SecondClass");


    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcFirst))
        return 0;   

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcSecond))
        return 0;

    hwndFirst = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("FirstClass"), TEXT("First Window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        700, 400, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    if(!hwndFirst)
        return 0;

    hwndSecond = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("SecondClass"), TEXT("Second Window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        700, 400, hwndFirst, 0, hInstance, 0);

    if(!hwndSecond)
        return 0;


    ShowWindow(hwndFirst, nShowCmd);
    ShowWindow(hwndSecond, nShowCmd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

After I close font dialog and second window, first window loses focus and goes to bottom. A window from another app shows on top. This only happens when I close font dialog, then close second window. If only first window and second window is showing, and I close second window, first window doesn't lose focus. If you want to test this, make sure there is another window from another app beneath this app before you test it. Why is the first window losing focus?

Comment: It has something to do with the 2nd window being an owned window.  Something else that goes majorly wrong is that the dialog isn't modal to the 1st window, probably related.  Poked at it for a while but I can't find the flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reproduce the same problem with MessageBox. Any time the second window is disabled/enabled (while the parent window is enabled the whole time) and the second windows is closed, the first window may not restore properly. `WS_POPUP` will fix that.

Another problem occurs when the second window is minimized while the first window remains on top. You remove `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` in second window to stop that. You can also use `SetFocus(GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER))` to reset focus

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SecondWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Test"), 0, 0);
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        SetFocus(GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER));//force parent window to restore
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    //...

hwndSecond = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, TEXT("SecondClass"), TEXT("Second Window"),
    WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 700, 400, hwndFirst, 0, hInstance, 0);
```